# Does ECMA6 do away with using prototype syntax as a best practice in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Example,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

> JavaScript classes are introduced in ECMAScript 6 and are syntactical
>   sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The
>   class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance
>   model to JavaScript. JS classes provide a much simpler and clearer
>   syntax to create objects and dealing with inheritance.

Does this mean I should stop using the language term `prototype` in my development, when ECMA6 is final and craft like this using the new syntactic sugar.  I believe they are the same other than that (from same page):

```
// unnamed
var Polygon = class {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
};

// named
var Polygon = class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
};
```

On the other hand, I see this,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

```
var obj = {
  foo() {},
  bar() {}
};
```

How does this all fit together?  What would I do with `var myObj`?  Can it have a constructor and the methods `foo()` and `bar()` like other languages?  Is this allowable?

```
var myObj = class myObj {
 contructor(height, width){
     this.height=height;
     this.width=width;
 },
  foo(this.height) {alert('the height is ' + this.height)},
  bar(this.height, this.width) {
      alert('the width is ' + this.width);
      var something = this.height + 5;
      alert('the height is : ' + something);

  }
};

var determine_something = new myObj(50,60);
determine_something.bar;
determine_something.foo;
```

(This did not work in an ECMA6 sandbox I tried)

This gives no errors, but `this.height` is undefined:

```
var myObj = class {
 contructor(height, width){
     this.height=height;
     this.width=width;
 }
  foo() {
    alert('the height is ' + this.height);
  }

};

var determine_something = new myObj(50,60);
determine_something.foo();
```

EDIT:  If I do not use `prototype`, and I want to add a new method, how do I do it with the new syntax?

Comment: Try the normal syntax. Why do you need the `var myObj` at all? The "standard" syntax is `class myObj {` (Unless it's important to use class expressions)

Comment: I don't know.  I saw several different ways on Mozilla's site.

Comment: These are drafts, and not official recommendations. I use the standard syntax a lot and it works fine. Maybe your sandbox doesn't support the class expression as described in this draft.

Comment: If you want to modify the prototype after definition, I think it will work with transpilers, but not necessarily in future implementations. Also, you'd lose lexical `this`, and that's one powerful feature to lose.

Comment: Isn't the draft in RC?  That seems close to reality.

Comment: "using prototype syntax" was never "a best practice in JavaScript"

Comment: @dandavis what is it?

Comment: The example that doesn't work is broken by `foo(this.height){` because `this.height` makes no sense as a function parameter, you still need to use `height` and assign it to `this.height`. And to your comment about `var obj = { foo() {} }`, that isn't a class it's just a normal object. Method syntax works on both. I think it would be useful to try to simplify this question a bit if possible.

Comment: Your last example will work as expected when you fix the typo `contructor` to `constructor`.

Comment: Not sure what the confusing is. As the description says, the class syntax is simply an alternative to writing a constructor function + prototype. Nothing more, nothing less. Objects (`var obj = { foo() {}, bar() {} };`) do not suddenly become obsolete.

Comment: It's not confusing as to what it does.  The problem is knowing what I am supposed to write in the future, what is expected by future developers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed/optimized version:

```
class MyObj {
    contructor(height, width){
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    foo() {
        alert(`the height is ${this.height}`)
    }

    bar() {
        alert(`the width is ${this.width}`);
        const something = this.height + 5;
        alert(`the height is : ${something}`);
    }
};

const determine_something = new MyObj(50,60);
determine_something.bar();
determine_something.foo();
```